# Edit XML stored as CLOB in an Oracle database

Tags: xml, oracle

I have a column which is a CLOB that contains a large XML document. Let's say that from my application a single node in the XML data is edited, is it possible I could update the CLOB without rewriting all the text stored in the database?

I am aware i could do something like that if I used XMLType instead of CLOB, but I cannot change the data type in the database.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on 11g, and the CLOB is a SECUREFILE, you can use [FRAGMENT_REPLACE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_lob.htm#CHDGBAHJ).